# When selecting item from an array renders all items react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following problem, when selecting an item through a checkbox and pressing a button so that that selected item is added to my new array, all the items are added.
I use the function map and return the component with their respective key and item:

```
renderFiltersInlcuye() {
    if(this.props.incluye){
        return this.props.incluye.map((item, index) =>{
            return <BusquedaPaquetesFiltrosAplicadosItems 
                key = {item.value}
                item= {item}
                onClickClose={this.removeItemIncluye.bind(this,index)}
            />
        })
    }
}
```

**And in my other component I render the following:**
render () {

```
    return(
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span className="badge badge-info " > 
                    <button onClick={this.props.onClickClose} type="button" className="close" ><i className="fas fa-times-circle"></i> </button> 
                    {this.props.item.texto}
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    );

}
```

Comment: Please include your code as text in the question instead of linking to external images.

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Is your `removeItemIncluye` function the one that is adding the item to the new array? If so, you should include the code for that function as that is likely where the problem lies. Your code doesn't currently appear to contain enough of the details to assist you in diagnosing the problem. For some tips on how to provide a complete example, check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.